# $f(x) = x^2 - 6x + 4$. What is the maximum value of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$?

Tags: exponential-function

The solution to this in my book says $\frac{1}{5}$. But greater values can be achieved by using $f(x)$ values approaching zero, right ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is not an exponential function. Before including tags, do read their descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a graph of $1/f(x)$:

[image]

Interpret.

Answer (score 1):

Your book confused a maximal value and a maximum, what he intended you to find is where(and at what value) $$(\frac{1}{f(x)})’=0$$
$$-\frac{2x-6}{x^2-6x+4}=0$$
$$x=3$$
$$\frac{1}{3^2-6*3+4}=-\frac{1}{5}$$

Answer (score 0):

Make use of
$|f(x)|\leq M$ then $|\frac{1}{f(x)}|\geq \frac{1}{M}$